# Binding router events from main view instance

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm having a hard time *"binding"* my routers events from my main view instance. My first thoughts are because the router only triggers my `Depths` collection. How would I properly notify my `viewpoint.js` about a page change?

**router.js**

```
var depth = depth || {};

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var DepthRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        '*page' : 'setPage'
    },

    setPage: function( page ) {
        // Set the current page
        page = page.trim() || 'home';

        // Trigger a collection {page} event
        depth.Depths.trigger(page);

    }

});

... // instance creation and Backbone.history.start() stuff

}());
```

**viewpoint.js**

```
var depth = depth || {};

$(function($) {
    'use strict';

    depth.Viewpoint = Backbone.View.extend({ 

        el: 'section#right > div.content',

        // Bind relevant triggers
        initialize: function() {

        },

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the change in your collection to your view.
Meaning that whenever you want to update the view of your collection this also happens.

For instance:

```
var list = new ModelList();

var listView = new ModelView1({model: list});    
var counterView = new ModelView2({model: list});
```

We have two view linked to the same colleciton model:
Now we bind to collection events:

```
ModelView1 = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize : function() {

        this.model.bind('add', this.render);
        this.model.bind('remove', this.render);
        this.model.bind('reset', this.render);
    }

ModelView2 = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize : function() {

        this.model.bind('add', this.render);
        this.model.bind('remove', this.render);
        this.model.bind('reset', this.render);
    }
```

Whenever the collection is fetched (**reset**) an item is added (**add**) or removed (**remove**) the render method will be invoked on your view(s)

Comment: What if my collection doesn't change yet I want my view to change when my router changes? Isn't that possible?

Comment: Of course, you can manually trigger a render event of the view. This can be done for instance via a global event you bind your view to.